# How to Read Sms when recieved in android api 33+ or in Andoird 8 and above

Tags: java, android, google-api

I Getting some problem how to read sms programmatically when sms received.. i try all the method and they are working on below android 8.
I Used On Recieved Method on Broadcast Reciever .. And every this fine and working but in android 7 and below version but not in Android 8 and above api...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.